# Как выделить область на карте Yandex?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Как выделить нужную мне область которая уже есть на карте Yandex. (Yandex карты) Например в городе УФА есть "Советский район", когда я нажимаю на название этой области, она выделяется.
Как это сделать в своем коде? То есть при нажатие на название какой либо области\города\страны выделялась это область. Желательно без сторонних сервисов, используя только **Yandex Mapkit**.

Пишу под Андроид

**P.S** Пожалуйста не судите строго, это мой первый вопрос в stackoverflow

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

В MapKit при поиске объекта можно запросить геометрию топонима через [setGeometry(true)](https://yandex.ru/dev/mapkit/doc/ru/com/yandex/mapkit/search/SearchOptions#setgeometryboolean). После получения нужного полигона его можно добавить на карту как и любой другой объект.